# What is low rank linear layer in neural networks?

Tags: machine-learning, speech-recognition

Going through the paper [`Convolutional Neural Network for Small-footprint Keyword Spotting`](http://cs229.stanford.edu/proj2017/final-reports/5244201.pdf). In the paper, authors have used low rank linear layer after convolution and max-pool layer.

What is the purpose of using this layer and how it is different from dense layer?

Comment: I would guess a linear layer with the weight matrix constrained to be of low rank?

Comment: Could you please provide me some links for further reading on this topic?

Answer (score 3):

The linked paper is not explicit on what they mean, however the most natural interpretation is the one suggested by @shimao, i.e. with "linear low-rank layer" they refer to a linear layer whose weight matrix is constrained to be of low rank.

In practice, if the transformation goes from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$ this can be implemented by:

$$ f(x) = UVx + b, \quad U \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times k}, V \in \mathbb{R}^{k\times n}, $$

with $k < min(n, m)$ being the desired rank for $UV \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$.

As you can see, the number of parameters for this linear layer is now $mk+nk$ instead of $mn$ (ignoring the bias), which for small values of $k$ means a lower number of parameters. This contributes to the regularization of the model and to a higher time efficiency for training and evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

It's not very explicit, but it just seems to be a linear transformation $ T(x) = Ax + b$ where $A,b$ are learned. In other words, it is just a dense layer without the non-linearity. It's not clear why they call it "low-rank"; perhaps they were thinking more along the lines of low VC dimension or something, compared to a regular fully-connected layer.